# Remote complex command not recognized in Powershell PSSession through script

Tags: windows, powershell, remoting

I am trying to write a short powershell script to accomplish some networking integration for software I am working on.

I have Powershell 4.0 working between 4 machines running both Win7 and Win8, and the connections function, and allow manual manipulation and execution.

However, when I try and write a script to automate the process, things start to misbehave.

Whet I am trying to do is execute a command on a remote machine like

```
F:\Folder\App.exe /xLICENSE.txt
```

App.exe takes the command-line input from /xLICENSE.txt and creates a file named LICENSE.txt in it's home directory with a unique user handle for use with certain application processes.

If I manually enter a new PSSession with a computer hosting App.exe, I can enter that command exactly as shown, and it executes the application, and produces the correct results.

However, when I attempt to integrate this command into a script, it keeps telling me that the command is not recognized as any command or cmdlet.

I have tried

```
$connection = New-Pssession -Computername NAME -Credential LOGIN
Invoke-Command -Session $connection -ScriptBlock {& "F:\Folder\App.exe /xLICENSE.txt"}
Remove-PSSession $connection
```

But it just gives me the error I described earlier.
I've also taken the command out of the quotations, and omitted the &, as well as replacing the command with a string containing the command (within quotations preceding an &)

And I also tried the line

```
Invoke-Command -Computername NAME -ScriptBlock {& "F:\Folder\App.exe /xLICENSE.txt"} -Credential LOGIN
```

and that doesn't work either. I've also tried the different ways to reference the command, using strings, and I've also tried passing the string in as a parameter to the invoke-command cmdlet, but nothing seems to work.

The only difference here is the Invoke-Command doesn't work if I do it manually...

If I remove the /x argument, then the script executes, but there's no way to prove that it did.
If I do any of the above with a cmdlet like, say, Get-ChildItem, then it will correctly show the contents of the home directory of the server I am connecting to.

I'm just sort of lost as to what I can do about this.
I had high hopes for Powershell, but if I can't get it to do this, it's going to be tough...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. 
After much trial and error, I determined that even though I am explicitly declaring the entire path to the App.exe command, I STILL need to change the working directory in the script before executing it. 
I do not need to do this when working locally, but I DO need to do it over network for whatever reason. 
It works fine now, and I can continue what I was doing!
I am still having trouble executing remote commands stored in strings, but that is a topic for another time.